# Discover Zeroconf/Bonjour Nodes?

Tags: bonjour, zeroconf

Is there an easy way to scan a given network for Bonjour/Zeroconf services?

I have a set of computers (Linux, Windows, Apple) and would like to auto-generate a list of all available Zeroconf-capable, networked nodes in my Intranet.

Comment: Did you make it work across subnets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used it, but you might want to take a look at the [Mono Project's Zeroconf library](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono.Zeroconf).

It looks like they have a query tool `mzclient` that may help you.

If nothing else, you should be able to build something in C# using that library.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted... Please let me know why. If I'm wrong, I profit from being corrected. :-)

Answer (score 7):

If using Linux and the [Avahi-Daemon](http://avahi.org/), it looks like Avahi-Discover is worth an investigation.

You'll obviously have to download/install/launch it though. On Ubuntu/Debian, you can use the following:

```
% sudo apt-get install avahi-discover
```

And launch GUI with:

```
% avahi-discover
```

Answer (score 2):

By far the most reliable method (I've tried all these, building a MDNS capable embedded product) is to use the opensource 'Bonjour'. This is the mDNSResponder daemon, and its available here:

http://opensource.apple.com/source/mDNSResponder/mDNSResponder-320.10/


mDNSResponder package has a Java JNI library and examples which let you poll all the available services.

Answer (score 1):

@EdH, thanks for your post. I up voted it. I haven't tried Mono.Zeroconf yet, but I am positive that it will work since Bonjour/Zeroconf has changed very little in the last couple years.  I am only looking for basic functionalities like service publish and discovery.  The mzclient seems a nice location to start with. I dug out the git location for the source: [mzclient on github](https://github.com/mono/Mono.Zeroconf/tree/master/src/MZClient) . Hope this helps others looking for a similar solution :-)

Comment: Anyone looking for zeroConf on .NET (C# so to speak) may also be interested in this [ZeroConf on codeplex](http://zeroconf.codeplex.com/)